# Call js function with image Button with php without submit

Tags: php, javascript, form-submit, imagebutton

Im coding php and i want to use image-button to call function.

```
$del= "<input type='image' src='delete.png' name='delete_cat' value='{$cat_name}' onclick='delete_exe(this.form,this.name,this.value)'  >";
```

This button is into a submit form

```
<form method="post" action="caffe_menu_category_post.php">

/form>
```

My problem is that when js function(`delete_exe()`) call and execute, then have auto-submit.
I don't want that. Is there any solution or alternative code?
Can i set submit off for my button?

Thanks in advance.

ps in my code i submit form with submit input

```
input type = "submit" value = "Submit Your Entries">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. i find the solution. I change my post form

```
form name="myForm" method="post" action="caffe_menu_category_post.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

And use javascripts

```
var val=true;
        function delete_exe(sel,kind,name){
                //Set val false to stop submit
                val=false;                          
        }


    function validateForm(){
        if(!val){
            //Stop submit
            return false;
            }
        }
```

So the auto-submit stop.
On the oher hand when click submit button i call js function to set val=true;

i don't know if these is the best solution, but it's work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return false;
```

in the end of your `delete_exe();` function. That will cancel submitting.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not my solution. I have the same auto-submit. Even if i don't call the function and have '$del= "<input type='image' src='delete.png' name='delete_cat' value='{$cat_name}'>' the click make submit.

Comment: So if your image should not submit this form, maybe change it to "standard" `<img/>` tag with `onClick` action binded?

Comment: It is more complicate than i want. I have multiple image-buttons so i want when click one of them, call javascript with 3 elements